# Hotkey doesn't work while interface is minimized

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, background-process, hotkeys

I created a simple auto clicker in visual basic using a timer and a couple of buttons.

I assigned keybinds to my start and stop buttons but they only work when the interface is open, and I want to use them while the program is minimized.

How might I go about doing that? Below is some of the more important code for context.  If you need more information just let me know.

```
Declare Sub mouse_event Lib "user32.dll" Alias "mouse_event" (ByVal dwFlags As Int32, ByVal dx As Int32, ByVal cButtons As Int32, ByVal dwExtraInfo As Int32, v As Integer)

Private Sub frmAutoClicker_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles MyBase.KeyPress
        If e.KeyChar = Microsoft.VisualBasic.ChrW(Keys.Z) Then
            btnStart.PerformClick()
        End If
  End Sub
 Private Sub btnStart_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnStart.Click

        Timer1.Start()

    End Sub
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        mouse_event(&H2, 0, 0, 0, 1)
        mouse_event(&H4, 0, 0, 0, 1)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try SetWindowsHookEx from user32.dll, it'a an aggressive method... but it will work.. (search SetWindowsHookEx in this forum...)

Or you couldtry to add a message filter to the application:

```
Application.AddMessageFilter
```

Comment: Thanks.  I'll try it out and let you know if it works

Answer (score 0):

You can use [RegisterHotkey](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-registerhotkey?redirectedfrom=MSDN) to implement VB.NET Detecting Keypress While Minimized.
It is the first step to know the [Virtual-Key Codes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/virtual-key-codes).

In order to facilitate the test, I set the automatic click limit of Timer1_Tick, which is limited to 50 times.

Sample code:

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

Public Class frmAutoClicker
Public Const WM_HOTKEY As Integer = &H312

Public Const VK_1 As Integer = &H5A   '0x5A  Z key
Dim i As Integer = 0

<DllImport("User32.dll")>
Public Shared Function RegisterHotKey(ByVal hwnd As IntPtr,
                    ByVal id As Integer, ByVal fsModifiers As Integer,
                    ByVal vk As Integer) As Integer
End Function

<DllImport("User32.dll")>
Public Shared Function UnregisterHotKey(ByVal hwnd As IntPtr,
                    ByVal id As Integer) As Integer
End Function

Declare Sub mouse_event Lib "user32.dll" Alias "mouse_event" (ByVal dwFlags As Int32, ByVal dx As Int32, ByVal cButtons As Int32, ByVal dwExtraInfo As Int32, v As Integer)

Private Sub frmAutoClicker_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim retVal1 As Boolean = RegisterHotKey(Me.Handle, 10, 0, VK_1)
    If retVal1 = False Then
        MsgBox("The hotkeys could not be registered!", MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
        Application.Exit()
    End If
End Sub

Protected Overrides Sub WndProc(ByRef m As System.Windows.Forms.Message)
    If m.Msg = WM_HOTKEY Then
        Dim id As IntPtr = m.WParam
        Select Case (id.ToString)
            Case "10"
                btnStart.PerformClick()
       End Select
    End If
    MyBase.WndProc(m)
End Sub

Private Sub frmAutoClicker_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As FormClosingEventArgs) Handles MyBase.FormClosing
    UnregisterHotKey(Me.Handle, 10)
End Sub
Private Sub btnStart_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnStart.Click
    Timer1.Start()
End Sub
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    If i > 50 Then
        Timer1.Stop()
        i = 0
    Else
        mouse_event(&H2, 0, 0, 0, 1)
        mouse_event(&H4, 0, 0, 0, 1)
    End If
    i = i + 1
End Sub

End Class
```

Result:

[image]